# xterm translations: sending multiple keys

Tags: keyboard, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, tmux, xterm

I'd like to utilize the multimedia keys on my keyboard in my xterm/tmux. I'd like to map the `XF86Launch8` to the keys `C-a F1` (`ctrl-a` being the tmux prefix key, the press `F1`, which is mapped in tmux to something).

C-a seems to have the keycode `^A`. `F1` is mapped to `OP`. The following xterm translation maps `XF86Launch8` to `F1`:

`XTerm*VT100.translations: #override <Key>XF86Launch8: string(0x1b) string("OP")`

The problem I have is with putting the `C-a` into the translation, because in TMUX I have to press `C-a`, release it and THEN press `F1` to activate the binding.

My question is: is there a way to set up an xterm translation for a key, so it would send `C-a`, 'release it', then send `F1`?

Answer (score 0):

The `translations` resource (a feature of the X Toolkit library) sends *characters*, not *press* and *release* events using the **`string`** *action*.

`tmux` cannot tell the difference, because it reads *characters*, not *press* and *release* events.

Possibly `tmux` wants a time delay between the control/A and F1, but doing that with `translations` would require an action that introduces a delay.  There is nothing suitable in the list of actions that `xterm` provides, and it does not seem something that is likely to be provided (since the nature of event-handling is that events are dealt with rapidly, rather than causing `xterm` to wait a while.